# Joining one row from one table with two rows from another table

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have Two tables with the following schema:

```
Location table:
Location_PK, Person_K, Status_K, Reason_K, Name etc some other columns

and Reference table:
Reference_PK, Description.
```

So for example a row in **Location** table might look like:
**L123, P4, R123, R456, "Freight building"**

and then **R123 and R456** are values that their primary keys can be found in **Reference** table

```
R123, "Roof repair"
R456, "Hail Damage"
```

Now I wanted to write a query that displays the information from Location table but instead of `R123,R456` can show the actual description from `Reference` table for them. This is the pseudo version of how I wrote the join `but it does not return any records.`
**Also** I want it output as a **dictionary** that the key is **Person_K** so later I can access the information for each person.

```
 public Dictionary<string, PersonLocationInfo> GetAllInfo(List<string> allProviderKeys)
    {
        var query = (from ea in this.Context.Locations
            join r1 in this.Context.Reference on ea.Reason_K equals r1.Reference_PK
            join r2 in this.Context.Reference on ea.Status_K equals r2.Reference_PK
            where (allProviderKeys.Contains(ea.Provider_K)
                )
            select new PersonLocationInfo
            {
                PersonKey = ea.Person_K,
                Reason = r1.Description.Trim(),
                Status = r2.Description.Trim()
            }
            ).ToDictionary(x => x.ProviderKey);

        return query;
    }

public class PersonLocationInfo
{
    public string Reason { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string PersonKey { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting records when you comment out the where clause ? Are you sure you have records in your tables for your where clause data ?

Comment: yes it was an issue with the WHERE clause. The join was fine.

Comment: Why don't you have navigation properties like `Location.Reason`, referring to a `Reference` object?

Comment: @GertArnold  No clue what you mean? And where and how you are thinking about using those?